# How do I scrape images from Uber Eats?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm attempting to scrape the src of images from a restaurant menu in Uber Eats in Python. I can get the menu item's name and description etc. but keep having issues with images.

Code:

```
def scrape_menu():
    url = 'https://www.ubereats.com/store/great-wall-restaurant/rgur-R7rST6iIkyYyfCkog?diningMode=DELIVERY'
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(url)

    
    lazyloads = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lazyload-wrapper')
    imgs = [x.get_attribute('src') for x in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//picture/img')]

    for img in imgs:
        print(img)

    driver.close()
```

The above code only spits out two srcs. Again makes me suspect a lazyloading issue.

When I print the lazyloads, it outputs elements similar to this with no `<picture>` or `<img>` inside. I think it must be an issue with the lazyloading on the page:

```
<div class="lazyload-wrapper"><div class="ii ij ik il im in ag io ih"></div></div>
<div class="lazyload-wrapper"><div class="ii ij ik il im in ag io ih"></div></div>
<div class="lazyload-wrapper"><div class="ii ij ik il im in ag io ih"></div></div>
```

Is there something I need to do with lazyloads to grab the images?

I am suspecting that's the hang up, but have been struggling to solve this.

The page I am attempting to scrape:
https://www.ubereats.com/store/great-wall-restaurant/rgur-R7rST6iIkyYyfCkog?diningMode=DELIVERY&pl=JTdCJTIyYWRkcmVzcyUyMiUzQSUyMjM3MTElMjBUZXJyYWNlJTIwRHIlMjIlMkMlMjJyZWZlcmVuY2UlMjIlM0ElMjI1NGZkZjM1My02OGM0LTJjZGEtNzVlMC1jMzI3M2MyZmJmYzQlMjIlMkMlMjJyZWZlcmVuY2VUeXBlJTIyJTNBJTIydWJlcl9wbGFjZXMlMjIlMkMlMjJsYXRpdHVkZSUyMiUzQTM4Ljg0MjgxNjclMkMlMjJsb25naXR1ZGUlMjIlM0EtNzcuMTg2MDIzMyU3RA%3D%3D

Answer (score 1):

For all 96 imgs after the infinite scroll you can do

```
imgs=[x.get_attribute('src') for x in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//picture/img")]
```

Also you used request where you can just use driver.page_source to solve your problem. Beautifulsoup doesn't mimic a client so Javascript isn't run so it returns empty.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

It should work with this by going through the elements until it updates the total count of elems.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get('https://www.ubereats.com/store/great-wall-restaurant/rgur-R7rST6iIkyYyfCkog?diningMode=DELIVERY')

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='wrapper']/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/button/div/*[name()='svg']"))).click()
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME=2
i=0
while True:
    elems=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//picture/img")))
    
    while i<len(elems):
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elems[i])
        i+=1

    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    elems2=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//picture/img")))
    if len(elems)==len(elems2):
        break

imgs = [x.get_attribute('src') for x in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//picture/img")))]

print(len(imgs))
print(imgs)
```

Comment: I'm only getting two image srcs out of it. I think it has to do the lazyloading of images on the page that I linked. Also I added my Selenium version with your code implemented

Comment: Let me write some code. It looks like it just goes straight down for the infinite page load.